# Pandas Dataframe iterating through two rows at a time

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using the following `Dataframe`:

```
      Price     Price2    Count  perc_change
0  0.000868    33782.17     4     1.000000
1  0.000872    33224.89     3     0.460829
2  0.000875    84110.85     7     0.344037
3  0.000878    67686.15     4     0.342857
4  0.000880    121400.22    4     0.227790
```

The following code:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

Returns one row at a time of the df `Dataframe` I was wondering if it is possible to iterate through two rows at a time?

Comment: The short answer is yes. You might have a look at `shift`. With so few details, hard to help more.

Comment: @AlexandreB. Thank you very much for your comment, I just added some more info to my question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with integer division for return 2 rows `DataFrame`s if possible:

```
#default RangeIndex
for i, g in df.groupby(df.index // 2):
    print (g)
```

General solution with `numpy.arange`:

```
for i, g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 2):
    print (g)
      Price    Price2  Count  perc_change
0  0.000868  33782.17      4     1.000000
1  0.000872  33224.89      3     0.460829
      Price    Price2  Count  perc_change
2  0.000875  84110.85      7     0.344037
3  0.000878  67686.15      4     0.342857
     Price     Price2  Count  perc_change
4  0.00088  121400.22      4      0.22779
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately I get the following error: `ValueError: Grouper and axis must be same length`

Comment: @Fozoro - Can you test second solution?

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake, works perfectly now. Thank you very much

Comment: the result of np.arange(len(df)) // 2  is [ 0 0 1 1 2 2 ...] . I dont see how groupby( [ 0 0 1 1 2 2 ...]) works! And who is i and g? thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

`iterrows` is `generator object`, so you just need to call `next` twice on it or use `zip`

```
t = df.iterrows()
for (i, row1), (j, row2) in zip(t, t):
    print(row1, row2)
```