# Insert Data and conditions on timestamp - Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime, timestamp

The column Flag correspond to the appearance of an alarm with its begin and the end with the timestamp column corresponding.

Rule: Each begin and the following end **must be in the same date** !

I have this piece of dataframe :

```
   Flag                     Timestamp
1  begin   2019-10-25 09:39:39.914889
2  end     2019-10-25 09:41:09.103102
3  begin   2019-10-25 10:39:58.352073
4  end     2019-10-25 10:40:06.266782
5  begin   2019-10-25 16:35:22.485574
6  end     2019-10-27 09:50:31.713192
7  begin   2019-10-29 14:04:33.095633
8  end     2019-10-29 14:05:07.639344
9  begin   2019-10-29 14:13:07.924966
10 end     2019-10-29 14:13:08.888890
```

On the line 5 I have a begin with the date 2019-10-25 and a end at the date 2019-10-27, so it's a problem.

So I have a solution but I can't implement it due to my lack of experience in pandas python.

To respect the rule 1, I would like to implement 2 treatments:

- add the missing dates **ONLY** in this specific case
- add opening and closing times **ONLY** in this specific case

specific case : exceeding the begin and end of the alarm over several days.

With our example:

```
  Flag                 Timestamp
  begin   2019-10-26 07:00:00.00  
  end     2019-10-26 17:00:00.00
```

and

```
  Flag                 Timestamp
  end     2019-10-25 17:00:00.00
  begin   2019-10-27 07:00:00.00
```

the result must be:

```
   Flag                     Timestamp
1  begin   2019-10-25 09:39:39.914889
2  end     2019-10-25 09:41:09.103102
3  begin   2019-10-25 10:39:58.352073
4  end     2019-10-25 10:40:06.266782
5  begin   2019-10-25 16:35:22.485574
6  end     2019-10-25 17:00:00.000000
7  begin   2019-10-26 07:00:00.000000 
8  end     2019-10-26 17:00:00.000000
9  begin   2019-10-27 07:00:00.000000
10 end     2019-10-27 09:50:31.713192
11 begin   2019-10-29 14:04:33.095633
12 end     2019-10-29 14:05:07.639344
13 begin   2019-10-29 14:13:07.924966
14 end     2019-10-29 14:13:08.888890
```

thanks for your patience and your time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

- Group the dataframe by 2 rows. This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57055020/10041823) explains how.
- For each group: we check the dates are the same day.

  - The length on a groupby let us know
  - If the two dates are the same day (e.g. `len() == 1`)

    - Returns the two dates
  - Else:

    - We generate a [`daterange`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) from the starting and ending date.
    - We duplicate each values with [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html)
    - We remove the first element and last one using [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iloc.html)
    - Because `repeat` duplicates values, we reset the index using [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html)
    - Then we change the type to [`pd.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html)
    - For all this dates, and becuse we just transformed them to `pd.Timestamp`, we can now use the [`pd.Timestamp.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.replace.html) method to set the hours (`8` or `17`).
    - Finally we add the `min` and `max` datetime to our list and return the whole.

---

**Code**

```
# Timestamp type
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])
# print(df)
#      Flag                  Timestamp
# 1   begin 2019-10-25 09:39:39.914889
# 2     end 2019-10-25 09:41:09.103102
# 3   begin 2019-10-25 10:39:58.352073
# 4     end 2019-10-25 10:40:06.266782
# 5   begin 2019-10-25 16:35:22.485574
# 6     end 2019-10-27 09:50:31.713192
# 7   begin 2019-10-26 16:35:22.485574
# 8     end 2019-10-27 09:50:31.713192
# 9   begin 2019-10-29 14:04:33.095633
# 10    end 2019-10-29 14:05:07.639344
# 11  begin 2019-10-29 14:13:07.924966
# 12    end 2019-10-29 14:13:08.888890


# Our function
def extends_dates(x):
    if len(x.groupby(x.Timestamp.dt.date)) == 1:
        return x.Timestamp
    else:
        # Create daterange
        d_range = pd.date_range(start=x.Timestamp.dt.date.min(), end=x.Timestamp.dt.date.max()) \
            .repeat(2) \
            .to_series() \
            .iloc[1:-1] \
            .reset_index(drop=True) \
            .apply(pd.Timestamp)
        # Set hours of all date
        news = [d.replace(hour=17) if i % 2 == 0 else d.replace(hour=8)
                for i, d in enumerate(d_range)]
        # Add min (from dataframe)
        news.insert(0, min(x.Timestamp))
        # Add max date (from dataframe)
        news.append(max(x.Timestamp))
        return pd.Series(news, name="Timestamp")

print(df)
# Timestamp type
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])

# Starting index to 0
df.index -= 1

# Create a dataframe from the series
out = df.groupby(df.index // 2).apply(extends_dates).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
print(out)
#                     Timestamp
# 0  2019-10-25 09:39:39.914889
# 1  2019-10-25 09:41:09.103102
# 2  2019-10-25 10:39:58.352073
# 3  2019-10-25 10:40:06.266782
# 4  2019-10-25 16:35:22.485574
# 5  2019-10-25 17:00:00.000000
# 6  2019-10-26 08:00:00.000000
# 7  2019-10-26 17:00:00.000000
# 8  2019-10-27 08:00:00.000000
# 9  2019-10-27 09:50:31.713192
# 10 2019-10-26 16:35:22.485574
# 11 2019-10-26 17:00:00.000000
# 12 2019-10-27 08:00:00.000000
# 13 2019-10-27 09:50:31.713192
# 14 2019-10-29 14:04:33.095633
# 15 2019-10-29 14:05:07.639344
# 16 2019-10-29 14:13:07.924966
# 17 2019-10-29 14:13:08.888890
```

I let you rebuild the `flag` column using [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for example.

**Code**:

```
import numpy as np
out["Flag"] = np.where(out.index % 2 == 0, "begin", "end")
print(out)
#                     Timestamp   Flag
# 0  2019-10-25 09:39:39.914889  begin
# 1  2019-10-25 09:41:09.103102    end
# 2  2019-10-25 10:39:58.352073  begin
# 3  2019-10-25 10:40:06.266782    end
# 4  2019-10-25 16:35:22.485574  begin
# 5  2019-10-25 17:00:00.000000    end
# 6  2019-10-26 08:00:00.000000  begin
# 7  2019-10-26 17:00:00.000000    end
# 8  2019-10-27 08:00:00.000000  begin
# 9  2019-10-27 09:50:31.713192    end
# 10 2019-10-26 16:35:22.485574  begin
# 11 2019-10-26 17:00:00.000000    end
# 12 2019-10-27 08:00:00.000000  begin
# 13 2019-10-27 09:50:31.713192    end
# 14 2019-10-29 14:04:33.095633  begin
# 15 2019-10-29 14:05:07.639344    end
# 16 2019-10-29 14:13:07.924966  begin
# 17 2019-10-29 14:13:08.888890    end
```

---

**Edit 1**

Running it two times doesn't change the output.

```
# 
# Timestamp type
df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])

# Starting index to 0
df.index -= 1

# Create a dataframe from the series
out = df.groupby(df.index // 2).apply(extends_dates).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()

out_2 = out.groupby(out.index // 2).apply(extends_dates).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
print(out == out_2)
#     Timestamp
# 0        True
# 1        True
# 2        True
# 3        True
# 4        True
# 5        True
# 6        True
# 7        True
# 8        True
# 9        True
# 10       True
# 11       True
# 12       True
# 13       True
```

Comment: with timestamp I have this problem : 
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Before running it, be sure to have `pandas.datetime` objects with `df["Timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Timestamp"])`

Comment: Yeah I tried this but When I did it :
---> 12         news.insert(0, min(x.Timestamp))
     13         # Add max date (from dataframe)
     14         news.append(max(x.Timestamp))

AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'Timestamp'

Comment: I rerun my answer and dont have any errors. Are you sure to run the full code ? Which Python version are you using ?

Comment: it work for the date!!! =) , but I don't understang how rebuild the flag with pd.where

Comment: My bad, it's numpy.where and not pd.where ! The edit explains how

Comment: If I execute a second time it, I don't have the good result. It works every other time.

Comment: That must come from the index. I make start the index at 0 to group them using `df.index // 2`. If you apply a second time `df.index -= 1`, you will have index starting at `-1`. I invite to try to understand the answer line by line..

Comment: yes but how to be sure that it is the right time every time? If it works every other time

Comment: Running the code 2 times doesn't change the output. I can't reproduce. See edit 1.

Comment: how can I pass 17h and 8h in parameters ? (extend_dates(x, OpenHour, CloseHour). But How apply it to out ?